# LateInitializationError: Field '_controller@36299353' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter

I am trying to fetch video link from server and run in mobile device but its fire error "LateInitializationError: Field '_controller@36299353' has not been initialized."

I am able to fetch successfully video link from API as well as Title also, but when i run the app its show me the error. Can any one please tell me where I wrote any wrong code?

Following are my code.

**Variable declaration**

```
//variable for video player
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  late Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
  Duration _position = Duration.zero;
  Duration _duration = Duration.zero;
  int _progress = 0;
  ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
```

**Calling API**

```
//Calling Api
  Future<VideoModel> getVideoStatus() async {
    var url = "${masterApiUrl}getVideoStatus.php?page=$currentPage";
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var jsondata = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    var _apiData = VideoModel.fromJson(jsondata);
    var newData = [...?dummyData.data, ...?_apiData.data];

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      if (_apiData.hasNextPage == 0) {
        refreshController.loadNoData();
      } else {
        refreshController.loadComplete();
      }
      final refids = newData.map((e) => e.id).toSet();
      newData.retainWhere((ids) => refids.remove(ids.id));
      dummyData.data = newData;
      return dummyData;
    } else {
      showToastMessage("some thing went wrong");
      return dummyData;
    }
  }
```

**Method for download video call back**

```
//Method for download video call back
  static downloadCallback(id, status, progress) {
    SendPort? sendPort = IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName("downloadingVideo");
    sendPort?.send(progress);
  }
```

**initState**

```
@override
  void initState() {
    //for video
    FlutterDownloader.registerCallback(downloadCallback);
    IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
        receivePort.sendPort, "downloadingVideo");
    receivePort.listen((message) {
      setState(() {
        _progress = message;
      });
    });

    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize().then((value) => setState((){}));
    //_initializeVideoPlayerFuture = initializeVideoPlayer();
    _controller.setVolume(1.0);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

**For showing video on screeen**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Video Status"),
      ),
      body: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: FutureBuilder<VideoModel>(
        future: getVideoStatus(),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            return SmartRefresher(
                controller: refreshController,
              enablePullUp: true,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.data!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index){
                  var serverData = snapshot.data!.data![index];
                  var globalLink = "https://Video_Status/";
                  var videoLink = globalLink+serverData.videoPath.toString();
                  print(videoLink);
                  print(_controller.value.isInitialized);
                  _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(videoLink)
                    ..addListener(() {
                      if (mounted) {
                        setState(() {
                          _position = _controller.value.position;
                          _duration = _controller.value.duration;
                        });
                      }
                    })..initialize();
                  print(_controller.value.isInitialized);

                  return Card(
                    elevation: 5,
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                    shape: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Center(
                            child: _controller.value.isInitialized ?
                            AspectRatio(aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                //behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                                onTap: (){
                                  setState(() {
                                    _controller.value.isPlaying ? _controller.pause() :
                                    _controller.play();
                                  });

                                },
                                child: Stack(
                                  children: [
                                    VideoPlayer(_controller),
                                    _controller.value.isPlaying ? Container():
                                    Container(
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        color: Colors.black26,
                                        child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow,color: Colors.white,size: 80,)),
                                    Positioned(
                                        bottom: 0,
                                        right: 0,
                                        left: 0,
                                        child: VideoProgressIndicator(_controller, allowScrubbing: true)),
                                    Positioned(
                                      bottom: 0,
                                      right: 0,
                                      child:
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                        child: Row(
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              _formatDuration(_position),
                                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11,color: Colors.white),
                                            ),
                                            Text("/",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,color: Colors.white),),
                                            Text(
                                              _formatDuration(_duration),
                                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11,color: Colors.white),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),),
                                    Positioned(
                                        right: 0,
                                        top: 0,
                                        child: IconButton(onPressed: () {
                                          print("download tap");
                                          _downloadFile(videoLink);

                                        },
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.download, color: Colors.white,),))
                                  ],
                                ),

                              ),) :
                            const CircularProgressIndicator()
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 5,),
                        Text(serverData.title.toString()),
                        Text("Download percentage   $_progress")
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                  }),

              onLoading: () async {
                print(snapshot.data!.hasNextPage.toString());
                if (snapshot.data!.hasNextPage == 0) {
                  refreshController.loadNoData();
                } else {
                  setState(() {
                    currentPage++;
                  });
                  // await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
                  // refreshController.loadComplete();
                }
              },
            );
          }else if (snapshot.connectionState ==
              ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text("Some thing went wrong !"),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: Text("Some thing went wrong"),
            );
          }
        },
      ),),
    ));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you haven't created the controller yet. try this, if it is still error, add async to initstate and await _controller.initialize()

```
VideoPlayerController _controller = VideoPlayerController();
  //late Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
@override
  void initState() {
    //for video
    FlutterDownloader.registerCallback(downloadCallback);
    IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
        receivePort.sendPort, "downloadingVideo");
    receivePort.listen((message) {
      setState(() {`enter code here`
        _progress = message;
      });
    });
 _controller.initialize().then((value) {
   if (mounted) 
setState((){_controller.setVolume(1.0);});});
    

    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: I have created controller but I try in this way as u say VideoPlayerController _controller = VideoPlayerController(); so its give me error "The class 'VideoPlayerController' doesn't have an unnamed constructor."

Comment: @TakiRajani it will be VideoPlayerController.XXX(); XXX Depending on the library you use to name the constructor, I'm just suggesting, don't copy my original